# Conversion LatLong to WGS84

Tags: math, dictionary, geolocation, geocoding

Please help with easy stuff.

I have geographical coordinates: latitude and longtitude.

I get them from leaflet event: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng
And I need to convert this stuff to WGS84 standard.

I know that it must be very easy but today google is mad on me...please any help.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. WGS84 is a datum. Latitude and Longitude are a projection. You can convert world coordinates either from one datum to another datum or from one projection to another projection.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know this theme so good. I know that I have latitude and longtitude, and I need to call a function, which requires coordinates in WGS84 standard.

Comment: Your latitude and longtitude may already be in the WGS84 datum.

Comment: Oh, I understand you. I'll check it when I'll get back home. Thanks for your time.